# What is the meaning of "make another case"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of or how could it be paraphrased the sentence "I make another case" in Louise Glück's *Matins*?

"Noah says / depressives hate the spring, imbalance / between the inner and the outer world. I make / another case - being depressed, yes, but in a sense / passionately / attached to the living tree..."

Comment: Although the interstice after "make" may break the normal meaning of the set phrase "make another case" in this instance, that normal meaning may still hold here—namely, "make another case" = "argue in favor of a different interpretation or explanation." On the other hand, "I make another case" can also (or instead) be read as meaning "I constitute a different case [in the medical sense of 'case' as meaning either 'patient' or 'physical or mental condition']." I doubt that the ambiguity is accidental.

Answer (score 1):

Rephrasing:

"I make another case..."

- I'd express a different view,
- I'd express a different opinion,

"being depressed, yes, but in a sense passionately attached to the living tree..."

- I may be depressive, but I still love the living tree.